# Alignment of Buttons in a toolbar right below menu buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to move some buttons to directly below the file menu. With what I have now, the buttons are at the top of the window, but keep appearing in the middle. I have tried to show the intended button layout below.

> `File` `Help`
>   `Add Employee` `Add Client` `Button3` `Button4`

This is the code I use

```
from Tkinter import *
class Application(Frame):

    def Donothing(self):
        pass
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.configure(height=500, width=1240)
        #*** Menu Bar ***
        menu=Menu(root)
        root.config(menu=menu)
        filemenu=Menu(menu,tearoff=False)

        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=self.Donothing)

        helpmenu=Menu(menu,tearoff=False)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
        helpmenu.add_command(label="About", command=self.Donothing)


        #*** ToolBar ***
        tool_bar=Frame(root,bg="blue")

        self.button_1=Button(tool_bar,text="Add Employee",command=self.Donothing)
        self.button_1.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.button_2=Button(tool_bar,text="Add Client",command=self.Donothing)
        self.button_2.pack(side=LEFT)
        tool_bar.pack(side=TOP)
        self.pack()


root = Tk()
root.title("Learnings")
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add Employee Add Client Button3 Button4 , should be below File menu !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand your toolbar:

```
tool_bar.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

[image]

Comment: `fill=BOTH, expand=1` is too much. All you need for a toolbar is `fill=X`. You don't want it to fill the whole window, you only want it to stretch across in the X direction. Notice the bad behavior when you expand the window using your solution -- the toolbar will grow in height.